# How big is Finery bonus?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

Basically as topic says: how big is *[Finery](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/crusader/passive/finery)* bonus?

Battle.Net description:

> **Finery**
>
> Gain Strength for every gem socketed into your gear.

How much *Strength* do you get from it? Is it equal to the gem quality?

For example, if I would use this skill and insert 1 *[Flawless Square Emerald](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/flawless-square-emerald)* in my weapon, would I get 34 *strength*? Or is there some constant value for it?

And according to [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/13407839/reaper-of-souls-launch-day-preparation-3-21-2014#launch%20times) the expansion should have already been released in Asia.

Comment: I think I remember seeing that it was +70 per gem but I'll have to find that info again

Comment: It's a shame they nerfed it to str instead of res

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 2.0.5 patch, the Finery skill was reworked to give from static 70 STR on character level 70 (further example: character lvl 67 had 67 STR bonus per socketed gem) up to 1.5% of your total STR before using Finery, per socket. It basically gives more STR for crusaders that are built to play T2 or higher in comparison to the skill before, and slightly lower STR bonus if you are doing sub T1 difficulties.

Note that difficulties here impose only an interpretation of how well your character is equipped, the skill is not directly affected with the difficulty change.

In numbers: let's say you have pants (2), chest (3), one weapon (1) and helmet (1), where the numbers in brackets impose number of sockets in the gear.

A character with 7000 base STR will get 105 STR bonus from each socket, resulting in 735 STR bonus (up from 490 before patch 2.0.5), which is a significant bonus.

Level 70 crusader with 4667 base STR will receive the same 70 STR bonus as before, but as the base STR goes up, so does the STR bonus from Finery passive.

99.9% of players should achieve 4667 base STR by the time they are level 70.

Answer (score 4):

I was playing my crusader last night. Even though I was low level, I was still able to check it.

The in-game tool-tip stated 60 strength per gem. This passive ability is granted at level 60, and I have seen accounts of it stating 70 at level 70.

So the amount of strength provided should be equal to your level (minimum 60).

Answer (score -4):

You gain 70 resistance to all elements for every different color gem socketed into your gear. If you have 5 different color gems socketed into your gear, you gain another 70 resistance to all elements.

Comment: This is referencing a previous version of the skill. The new version provides a strength bonus and does not care about the color of the gem.